# Grouped Collapsible Navigation Control Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am looking for a grouped collapsible navigation control for use in one of the Windows 8.1 apps 
I have searched quite a bit and am not able to find this control.
However I do find few existing apps in the store using this control, the mail app being one such example.
 Is there any collapsible grouped control available ?
Else I figure I should use a custom control with a `button` and an attached `flyout`
But the flyout would disappear if the user clicks anywhere else in the screen.

[image: Navigation Control in the Windows Mail App]

Comment: Pre-existing, I don't think so. However it wouldn't be very difficult to make an accordion style control of your own to mimic it with something like an ItemsControl with as the ItemTemplate a custom styled RadioButton and a Panel like a Grid or something that toggles its Visibility based on the IsChecked state of the Button.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 has an Expander control in the form of the Windows Phone Toolkit but the performance is very poor when put into a ListView as you would do if you were trying to mimic the built in email app. The best way I've found to get the behavior you're after is to put all of the group header items into the ListView then use an ItemTemplateSelector to choose the visual appearance of group headers vs their items, then only add the child items (to the main ListView) when the group header is expanded. It sounds complicated but I wrote a blog about it [here](http://ereethahksors.blogspot.com/2015/01/expandablecollapsable-listview-items-in.html) and there is a source example of it [here](https://github.com/hippiehunter/Baconography/blob/appx/SnooStream/SnooStream.Shared/View/Controls/SelfActivityView.xaml) and [here](https://github.com/hippiehunter/Baconography/blob/appx/SnooStreamCore/ViewModel/SelfStreamViewModel.cs)